# App crashed when registering gcm token (got ExceptionInInitializerError)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to register a gcm token but got exceptions.

The os version in my android device is android 5.0.

Here is my code to register gcm token.

```
 public static String refreshRegistationId(final Context context) {
    String token = "";
    try {
        // [START register_for_gcm]
        // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
        // are local.
        // [START get_token]
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(context);
        // R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (the Sender ID) is typically derived from google-services.json.
        // See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start for details on this file.
        token = instanceID.getToken(SENDER_ID,
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        // [END get_token]
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
        NidusTool.putStringSharedPreference(context, GCM_REGISTER_TOKEN, token);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        // sendRegistrationToServer(token);

        // Subscribe to topic channels
        // subscribeTopics(token);

        // [END register_for_gcm]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
    }
    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    // Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    // LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    return token;

}
```

`ExceptionInInitializerError` occurs when calling `instanceID.getToken(SENDER_ID,GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null)`

The stack trace is

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:306)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1072)
    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
    at java.security.Signature.tryAlgorithmWithProvider(Signature.java:217)
    at java.security.Signature.tryAlgorithm(Signature.java:203)
    at java.security.Signature.getSignature(Signature.java:175)
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:105)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my dependencies in gradle.

```
// for gcm to use support-annotations 23.0.1
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

I do not understand why I got such exception.

Thank you.

Comment: have you check your manifest and using the Internet Permission?

Comment: Can you compile against Play Services 8.3 `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'` and see if this is resolved?

Comment: Hi, this problem happens at random. Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it fails and throws the exceptions.

Comment: Hi @KayAnn , how can I compile against play service? Is it not enough even the apk is built successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Change the dependency in your buil.gradle from:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'`

to:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'`

Also, check SDK manager in Android Studio to make sure you have downloaded the latest version/revision of Google Play Services.

So once you change the dependencies, sync your project and you should be all set. [More info](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

PS: For future reference, please note that you could find answers to similar questions by doing quick search within this community or Google search.